# .net core restful api return json with content type application/json

Tags: json, rest, .net-core

I want to create a restful api using .net core. The api will retrieve data from oracle db to a datatable / dataset and then return json data. But fail to do so.

How can I return a valid json like result A with the Content-Type: application/json?

```
    [HttpGet]
    // [Produces("application/json")] **** <---- return invalid JSON if this code is added
    public ActionResult Get()
    {   
        cmd = new OracleCommand(pQuery, _conn);
        oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        oda.Fill(dt);

        string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
        return Ok(jsonStr);
    }
```

Result A:
**Content-Type: text/plain**
[{ "id": 111, "name": "peter" },{ "id": 222, "name": "john" }]

Result B:
// [Produces("application/json")] **** <---- if add this code it will return json like this
**Content-Type:application/json**
"[{\"id\": 111, \"name\": \"peter\" },{ \"id\": 222, \"name\": \"john\" }]"

Comment: Problem is solved by changing the Ok(jsonStr) to Content(jsonStr, "application/json"). Thanks all.

Comment: you can also let the controller serialize the body based on the `Accept` header, just `return Ok(dt);`